# Azure vm stopped unexpectedly, says "Storage account xxxxxxxx not found,...."

Tags: azure, azure-storage

My Azure VM with Windows server 2016 stopped unexpectedly today. When I tried RDP today in my vm, it was saying 'machine unavailable'. So I logged in to Azure portal, and the VM was actually running. But when I tried to restart it, I got a notification saying

"Failed to restart virtual machine xxxxx. Error: Storage account xxxxxxxx not found. Ensure storage account is not deleted and belongs to the same location as the VM."

But, I was successfully using the vm till today. I didn't do anything in the Azure portal. The storage account with the vhd still exists (in the same resource group). I once deleted an unused storage account about 2 months ago, but the VM was running perfectly till today. I am not sure about anything that may have happened. The activity logs are empty.

Comment: Do you have any other co-Admin under your subscription? Please have a try to check whether the vhd file is locked in the Azure Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Create a new storage account with the name – 'xxxxxxxx' in the same region as VM and then restart the VM to mitigate the failed error.

---

**Why?**

It is looking for already deleted storage account. This happens mostly for diagnostics storage accounts (I can't exactly say whether this is a diagnostics one without knowing the account name. diagnostics account names are something like xxxxxxdiag). Sometimes, disappearance of diagnostic account doesn’t cause the VM to be unreachable but the VM would just be marked as ‘failed’ over the portal.

Comment: Why should this be done? Some explanation might help the person asking the question.

Comment: It is looking for already deleted storage account. This happens mostly for diagnostics storage accounts (I can't exactly say whether this is a diagnostics one without knowing the account name. diagnostics account names are something like xxxxxx**diag**). Sometimes, disappearance of diagnostic account doesn’t cause the VM to be unreachable but the VM would just be marked as ‘failed’ over the portal. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual machine stopped unexpectedly and is not available again, we can report the issue to the Azure support team from the Azure portal.  Please have a try to confirm with the Azure support team whether it can be recovered. 
According to your description that the VHD file is existing in the storage.   We also can recovery the machine from the VHD file. More detail steps please refer to another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327590/create-vm-from-existing-vhd-preview-portal).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be because the diagnostics storage account for the VM is deleted. You can solve this issue by Redeploy your VM under `Support + Troubleshooting` tab in the VM blade. See image:

[image]